# Dynamic Pivot Tables based on Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I need some assistance pivoting my data in SQL Server.  I have tried several online PIVOTs but they either are for static values or aggregate the data somehow which I don't want.  Ideally I want to return the data based on the project id and flip it so I can present in a different way.

My current table stores data like this:

| Project Id | Projected Month | Labor | Equipment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-01 | 500 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021-10-01 | 250 | 250 |
| 1 | 2021-11-01 | 100 | 50 |
| 2 | 2021-11-01 | 100 | 50 |
| 2 | 2021-12-01 | 100 | 50 |

My desired output when selecting Project Id = 1 would be:

|  | 2021-09-01 | 2021-10-01 | 2021-11-01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Labor | 500 | 250 | 100 |
| Equipment | 0 | 250 | 50 |

My desired output when selecting Project Id = 2 would be:

|  | 2021-11-01 | 2021-12-01 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Labor | 100 | 50 |
| Equipment | 100 | 50 |

Any assistance/links would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your table for project id 2 is flipped around a bit - no value for Equipment in the source table is 100.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you have?

Comment: SQL2012.  I have tried per these docs but they are for fixed number or columns and/or they aggregate the data.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty custom requirement, and I'm not surprised you haven't found a ready-made sample to copy and paste that fits your exact needs.

You can see post revisions for previous solutions but I think this is my favorite:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DoThePivotThing
  @ProjectId int
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max), 
          @agg  nvarchar(max),
          @sql  nvarchar(max);

  SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',
  ' + QUOTENAME([Projected Month])
    FROM dbo.Projects WHERE [Project Id] = @ProjectId
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value
    (N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'');

  SELECT @agg = STUFF((SELECT ',
  ' + QUOTENAME([Projected Month]) 
    + ' = MAX(' + QUOTENAME([Projected Month]) + N')'
    FROM dbo.Projects WHERE [Project Id] = @ProjectId
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value
    (N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'');

  SET @sql = N';WITH x AS (
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Projects 
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1,''Labor'',Labor),
                   (2,''Equipment'',Equipment)) AS v(o,t,v)
    PIVOT (MAX(v) FOR [Projected Month] 
        IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) AS piv
  )
  SELECT Cost = t, ' + @agg + N' FROM x GROUP BY t,o ORDER BY o;';

  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@ProjectId int', @ProjectId;
END
```

> ```
> EXEC dbo.DoThePivotThing @ProjectId = 1;
> ```

| Cost | 2021-09-01 | 2021-10-01 | 2021-11-01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Labor | 500 | 250 | 100 |
| Equipment | 0 | 250 | 50 |

> ```
> EXEC dbo.DoThePivotThing @ProjectId = 2;
> ```

| Cost | 2021-11-01 | 2021-12-01 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Labor | 100 | 100 |
| Equipment | 50 | 50 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=440241892e1169ce52c6fc3a87fc771f)

Answer (score 1):

I used dynamic sql for pivoting to generate the output. This is one approach, You may find many solution paths to reach to your output.

```
  Create table Projects
   (
      ProjectID  int
      ,[ProjectedMonth] Date
      ,Labor Int
     ,Equipment int
   )
Insert into  Projects values (1,'2021-09-01', 500, 0)
 , (1,'2021-10-01', 250,250)
 , (1,'2021-11-01', 100,50)
 , (2,'2021-11-01', 100,50)
 , (2,'2021-12-01', 100,50)

 DECLARE @Project_Id AS VARCHAR(10) = '2'
 DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

 SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(a.[ProjectedMonth]) 
    FROM  Projects [a]
    WHERE ProjectID = @Project_Id
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'')


  Set @query = '
   SELECT ''Labor'' as [title], *   
       FROM   
         (select  labor,[ProjectedMonth]  from  Projects where CAST(ProjectID AS VARCHAR(10)) =' + @Project_Id +') p  
       PIVOT  
        (  MAX (labor)  
           FOR [ProjectedMonth] IN  
        ( ' + @cols+ ' )  
      ) AS pvt 
      
      UNION ALL
      
       SELECT ''Equipment'' as [title], *   
    FROM   
     (select  Equipment,[ProjectedMonth]  from  Projects where CAST(ProjectID AS VARCHAR(10)) =' + @Project_Id +') p  
    PIVOT  
      (  MAX (Equipment)  
        FOR [ProjectedMonth] IN  
      ( ' + @cols+ ' )  
      ) AS pvt   ;'



  --select @query
  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @query
```

[image: When ProductID is 2]

[image: When ProductID is 1]

Comment: It is a pivot (2 pivots with Union all as you have two identical results ). if this  can be accepted, please do accept thanks